# Swift string array keeps showing up empty

Tags: arrays, swift

I've got a function that will connect to my parse database and go through all the user objects and append their names and emails to a string array for each category.

When I debug it it shows the arrays as having the correct values during the viewWillAppear function but when it comes down to returning the amount of rows in the array they are empty for some reason.

Any idea what is causing this?

Here is my code

```
 import UIKit
 import Parse

class ContactTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//arrays to hold user's name and email
var users_names = [String]()
var users_emails = [String]()


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){

    //Load user email and name
    let query: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) users.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let user_objects = objects {
                for user in user_objects {
                    self.users_names.append(user.valueForKey("name") as! String)
                    self.users_emails.append(user.valueForKey("email") as! String)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
        self.users_names.removeAtIndex(1)
        self.users_emails.removeAtIndex(1)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.8353, green: 0.9098, blue: 0.902, alpha: 1.0)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

//return number of rows in table
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users_names.count
}
```

The problem is cellForRowAtIndexPath is running and populating the table before viewWillAppear() runs and fetches the data into the array.

I've tried adding this at the start of viewWillAppear

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

And Then .endIgnoringInteractionEvents() at the end of viewWillAppear but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Track every steps. Is `for user in user_objects` block run? What is the number of array before `self.users_names.removeAtIndex(1)`?

Comment: On which line is the value correct when debugging?

Comment: The number is 9 and then I do the removeAtIndex to remove the admins email from the list so he can't email himself and it's at 8.  I figured out what's happening is the celfforrowatindexpath function is running before viewwillappear finishes it's process.   I'm not sure how to pause the cellfforrowatindexpath from running before viewwillappear.

Comment: I tried putting this in the first line of viewwillappear      'code' UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()     But it didn't fix it

Comment: FYI, You should really be doing this in viewDidLoad

Comment: I've tried moving the parse call into viewDidLoad and the error still persists.  Is there a reason why viewDidLoad is preferred over viewWillAppear?

Comment: tableView.reloadData should cause the tableview to refresh it's data, but you may have a threading issue as stated in an answer

Comment: viewDidLoad is sort of the introduction point for the VC. That's where you should start any background actions.especially if you only need to load your data once, this will cause it to be available the quickest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` from your block, which is running on a background thread. All UI-related operations must run on the main thread. Try wrapping the call to reload like this:

```
self.users_names.removeAtIndex(1)
self.users_emails.removeAtIndex(1)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I've moved tableview.reloadData() out of the parse block and into the viewWillAppear block and added dispatch_async to it but error still persists.

Comment: It still needs to be in the parse block.